# why server.transfer process slow in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, server.transfer

I need your help, I have a problem with server.transfer code in vb.net, it runs so slow..
My Question:

1. Why does it run slowly (take 5 minutes to move between web pages (.aspx))?
2. What should i check for this trouble?
3. Is it because operating system? Im use windows 7, before i used windows XP there is no problem like this...
4. is server.transfer related to database connection (not sure)? I use mysql (XAMPP packages).
5. Or may be because other configuration that i miss out in windows seven.
   FYI: i try in several web browser same result(loading 5 minutes)..

Thank every one that answer my question, thank you very much!

Comment: If you create a new project, add two pages, have one do the transfer to the other, and run it, does it exhibit the same issue?

Comment: i have tried, not.. or is it because of the session,... hmmm

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've found on this is that it can have to do with the status code the transferred page returns. If it returns a 500 error, it can make your server transfer run upwards of five minutes.

One way to test this, if you can, is to run the transferred page in isolation and generate any of the information being transferred on the other side to see if any errors are generated.

It took me a day to figure this out. Hopefully it helps someone else.